# Native JavaScript equivilent of text() for single selected element

Tags: javascript

How would I return `Some Text`, `<a href="abc.html">Some Anchor</a>`, and `<img src="abc.jpg" />` from the following three elements without using jQuery?  In other words, how would I return `$('#t1).text()`, `$('#t2).text()`, `$('#t3).text()` without using jQuery?  I don't need to return an array if multiple elements as I will only select one element at a time.

```
<td id="t1">Some Text</td>
<td id="t2"><a href="abc.html">Some Anchor</a></td>
<td id="t3"><img src="abc.jpg" /><td>
```

jQuery does text() as follows. It seems overkill since I am not worried about returning an array for multiple elements.

```
text: function( value ) {
    return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
        return value === undefined ?
            jQuery.text( this ) :
            this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
},
```

Thanks

Comment: `$('#t2')` would return `Some Anchor`, not `<a href...`. Same for `$('#t3')`.

Comment: Can you just read the `innerHTML` property after using `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer.  No, it will only work for the <a> and <img>, not the text node.

Comment: do you need to handle this case `<a>a <b>b</b> c</a>` and retrieve `a b c`?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine.  You are right.  I guess it would be equivalent to .html().

Comment: @rambocoder.  I could, but it probably isn't necessary.  Just using it for a sort plugin.  It might be nice to strip out the HTML and just sort on the content, but the same results with the HTML (maybe makes the sort take a little longer?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve the text of a node(s) like so:

```
var el = document.getElementById("t1");
var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;
```

Some more info on textContent and innerText on the MDN site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Comment: Ah ha!,  Thanks!  I first was using el.data, and it worked without the html elements.  Later tried innerHTML, and it erred on the text values.  Just curious, why textContent over data, and innerText over innerHTML?

Comment: @user1032531 innerText is IE's version of textContent. One thing to watch out with innerText is that it won't return hidden text. For more info look at the link to MDN. They explain it much better then I ever could :)

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a property on Nodes to get its data (non recursive). `innerHTML` is the HTML, a property on Elements. `textContent` is the standard property to get the text (without HTML) of an Element. `innerText` is the non-standard old-IE way to get `textContent`.

You now should know what you need :-)

Comment: Thanks Florian,  Now I know more!